# ideals of polynomial ring of two variables generated by two elements

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, ac.commutative-algebra, prime-ideals, monomial-ideals

Let $f,g$ be two polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, given by
$$
f(x,y)=x^4-3xy+y^2,$$

$$
g(x,y)=x^5-4xy+3xy^2.$$

Let $I=(f,g)$ be the ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ generated by $f$ and $g$.

Is $x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,x^6,x^7,x^8, x^9, x^{10}, x^{11}$ lies in $I$ respectively?

Comment: I believe you can solve this in sage, possibly online with a browser. Session:  `KK.<x,y>=QQ[];I=Ideal([x^4-3*x*y+y^2,x^5-4*x*y+3*x*y^2]);x^2 in I`

Comment: thanks so much! could you give me the programme website?

Comment: Sure, just to make try to export the web example. Sage is free software: http://sagemath.org/. If your platform isn't supported, you can run it locally in virtual machine.

Comment: For browser, create account on: https://cloud.sagemath.com. Create sage worksheet and paste my example, then choose |RUN|. Better replace ";" by newline, newlines are non-trivial in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending on @joro's answer: open a [public sagemathcloud worksheet](https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/20e4a191-73ea-4921-80e9-0a5d792fc511/files/ideals-polynomial.sagews)

```
KK.<x,y>=QQ[]
I=Ideal([x^4-3*x*y+y^2,x^5-4*x*y+3*x*y^2])
x^2 in I
```

[image: sagemathcloud polynomial ideal]

Comment: How did you make it public?